# Swift - Play animation right before a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've got a two View Controllers, when user press a button on the first one - app segue to the second one. But problem is that I need to use custom animation of segue. There is array of images, that must be animated before segue.

I guess that I need to create child-class myStoryboardSegue and override some method, but I don't even know which one.

Hope you can help me to understand.

Comment: You could just use a custom view controller transition to perform your animation as part of the segue.

Comment: @Anorak is right. If the Animation is only visible at your first ViewController, you could also start an `Animation` and call your `Segue` in your animations completion block

Comment: Something like this: http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/